Lightning web component JS file explaination
can someone please explain (with an example if possible) what does the below statements in LWC js file refer to:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class FirstComp_lwc extends LightningElement {}

I get that we are importing modules and exporting the current class. But I want to understand the following:  why we are importing LightningElement?
Then why we are exporting current JS file as class? 
also, why we are again extending the LightningElement{}? 
It would be great if someone can explain above asked questions.
thanks

The keyword extends is used by a class (that's why your component must be a class) to create a subclass that extends its features. That's the idea of inheritance: when you want to create a new class and there is already a class that includes some of the code that you need, you can derive your new class from the existing one.
LightningElement class is a custom wrapper of the standard HTML element.
You must extend it and export your class as default to be able handle UI elements and to to make your component available to other UI ones. Of course, to do so (to use LightningElement) you have to import it.
In your js file you can have multiple named export, but only one default export in your module (every JS file in Lightning web component is a JS module).
Named exports are used by standard modules too, indeed most of (if not every ) wire adapter are imported using named import syntax, i.e.
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

Note that while importing this adapter, named exports must be referred to by the exact same name, but the default export can be imported with any name. This means that your class, the one exported as default, can have any name, even one different from the js file, and everything will keep working. Anyway the convention is for the class name to be Pascal Case and share the name with the js file, i.e. for myComponent.js the class name will be MyComponent.
Be aware that if you need a component to organize your functions or constants and reuse them in multiple components, you don't need to import and use LightningElement and you don't need the html file. In this case you'll have a component structure like:
lwc
  ├──yourUtils
     ├──yourUtils.js
     └──yourUtils.js-meta.xml


You need to import LightningElement because you are using in the next statement in the extends clause.
If the LWC is a regular element, it needs to extends LightningElement.  But some LWCs may not.  Example...
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';
export default class MyModal extends LightningModal {
...

You are exporting your class so that it may be called from elsewhere.
